# Format Rest API data returned by UTL_HTTP.REQUEST get request and store in Oracle DB

Tags: json, xml, database, oracle, api

I am getting data from a rest API using **UTL_HTTP.REQUEST** utility of Oracle. It is returning me the data in a single column and it splits the data and fetches only first **2000** characters. Is there any way I can get the complete data and store it in a table in Oracle with same number of columns 
**(id,
employee_name,
employee_salary,
employee_age,
profile_image).** 
I have attached the screenshot that shows what it returns

[image]

Comment: Which version of Oracle? Built-in JSON support is available at varying levels from 12c, allowing you to either store the JSON result intact and then extract elements from it, or split it into relational data. (Lots of info in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/index.html), or [overview here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-store-query-and-create-json-documents-in-oracle-database)). Anyway, your client is only *showing* you the first 2000 characters by default; if you click that entry you should see an option to view the entire value.

Comment: From an earlier question you might be on 11g; in which case you could have a look at [PL/JSON](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) maybe.

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole,  I'm using Oracle 11G. Also I have copied the data in external text file by pressing Ctrl+Shift+C and also created a table and tried to input the data in it. Still it stores only first 2000 characters. Any hints why is it doing this?

Comment: Right, I missed what you were actually calling... [utl_http.request](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_http.htm#ARPLS71076) "returns up to the first 2000 bytes of data retrieved from the given URL" so this is expected behaviour. Look at the examples in that documentation to see how to handle bigger responses.

Comment: Sure, I will check this. Thank you